# Direct sum of range(B) and kernel(B*)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Is it true that for some matrix $B$ of dimension $d\times d$, $ker(B) \oplus Range(B^*) = \mathbb{C}^d$???.

I know that dim$(Range(B)) + $dim$(ker(B)) = $dim$(\mathbb{C}^d)$ but I don't know how to prove the other one.

How could I prove it?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's true since $Range (B^*)=(\ker B)^\perp$. In fact

$$x\in\ker B\iff \forall y\in \Bbb C^n,\quad 0=\langle Bx,y\rangle=\langle x,B^*y\rangle\iff x\in (Range (B^*))^\perp$$
and in finite dimensional space we have for a subspace $F$ of $\Bbb C^n$

$$F\oplus F^\perp=\Bbb C^n$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize that $⟨Bx,y⟩=⟨x,B^*y⟩$ was true by properties of conjugate transpose :)

Answer (score 1):

If $B^2=B$, then $ker(B)\oplus Range(B)=\mathbb{C}^d$.

We prove that $ker(B)\cap Range(B)=0$

Proof: If $x\in Range(B)$, then $x\notin Ker(B)$.

For if $Bx\neq 0$, then $B(Bx)=B^2x=Bx\neq0$.